# Email field is not migrated

Tags: 9, migrations

I am trying to migrate an email field from Drupal 7 profile2 (don't think that matters) and it becomes blank on the Drupal 9 instance. The remaining fields migrate without any issues.

My process plugin generated from migrate_plus:

```
  field_email:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: field_email
      process:
        value: email
```

I tried to just do `plugin:get` and it doesn't work either.

[image]